# Difference between pm clear and pm uninstall -k on Android

Tags: android, command, adb

from pm help, I get this:

```
pm uninstall: removes a package from the system. Options:
    -k: keep the data and cache directories around after package removal.

pm clear: deletes all data associated with a package.
```

Does this mean that when I do `pm uninstall` (without `-k`) it deletes all files which would `pm clear` delete? Or in other words, when I do specify `-k` for uninstallation command, it leaves files undeleted. When I do `pm clear` on that package, the files which will be cleared are exactly these I have left undeleted by `-k` option?

Is it possible that by doing `pm uninstall` and after that `pm clear`, I can even delete some files which have not been deleted by `pm uninstall`?

Comment: Question about end-user utilities, like pm and os management are off-topic at so

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your understanding is correct:

- `pm uninstall` removes everything
- `pm uninstall -k` removes the app,
  leaves the user data intact (to be used if the app is reinstalled)
- `pm clear` only removes the user data associated with the package,
  but not the package itself